# $A$ is a $k$-algebra, and $m$ is a maximal ideal. Is it possible that $m = m^2$ but $A$ not a field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> $A$ is a $k$-algebra, and $m$ is a maximal ideal. Is it possible that $m = m^2$ but $A$ not a field?

If $A$ is a Noetherian domain, for instance, then I think that the Krull intersection theorem would imply that $m = 0$, so that $A$ is a field.

I think this should remain true even if the assumption that $A$ is a domain is dropped, just because taking unions of varieties should make the tangent space bigger. But I am not sure.

Geometrically, I would want there to be a positive dimensional tangent space at a closed point of a scheme with positive dimension. But I guess weird things can happen in life...

Comment: If $R$ is a noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, then $\dim \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 \geq \dim R$. Geometrically, the cotangent space at a point on a (noetherian) variety must have dimension bigger or equal to the dimension of the variety itself (this addresses your last point only).

Comment: No you can't drop the condition that $A$ is a domain. For example, the ideal $m=A\times \{0\}$ in $A\times k$ for $k$ a field is maximal (since $(A\times k)/m=k$) and satisfies $m^2=m$. But it is not zero. Geometrically, I just took a space $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and added a closed point elsewhere. The tangent space at that point is 0 dimensional.

Comment: @Roland Oh, of course. So this is one reason why the locality assumption msteve gave is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=K[X]/(X^2-X)$. Obviously, $A$ is not a field (in fact, $A\simeq K\times K$), and $x^2=x$ in $A$. Set $M=(x)$. Then $M^2=M$.

Comment: In this example we have $M=M^2$ for *all* maximal ideals of $A$.